# Inline Gridview Updating

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, gridview

When I click update in GridView I get an error message saying

> Input String was not in the correct format

I'm pretty sure I input the proper string. I'm not sure what is wrong with the code. Please advise.

```
protected void GridView3_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
 {

    bool isUpdated = false;
    //getting key balue, row id
    int subjectID = Convert.ToInt32(GridView3.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Value.ToString());
    //getting row field details
    TextBox Assigned = (TextBox)GridView3.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("Assigned");
    TextBox Location = (TextBox)GridView3.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("Location");
    TextBox Notes = (TextBox)GridView3.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("Notes");

    using (SqlConnection sqlCon = new SqlConnection())
    {
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
        {

            //added "@" for continuous tring in new line    
            cmd.CommandText = @"UPDATE Inventory SET Assigned=@Assigned, Location=@Location, Notes=@Notes";
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Assigned", Assigned.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Location", Location.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Notes", Notes.Text);
            cmd.Connection = sqlCon;
            sqlCon.Open();
            isUpdated = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() > 0;
            sqlCon.Close();
        }//end using
    }//end using

    if (isUpdated)
    {
        status.Visible = true;
        status.Text = "" + Assigned.Text + "Data added successfully!";
        status.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
    }//end if

    else
    {
        status.Visible = true;
        status.Text = "Error while updating" + Assigned.Text + "data details";
        status.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;

    }//end else

    GridView3.EditIndex = -1;
    BindData();

}//end row updating
```

the error is coming from

> int subjectID = Convert.ToInt32(GridView3.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Value.ToStrong());

Thanks!

Comment: In your watch window, see what the value of "GridView3.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Value.ToString()" is.  I'm willing to bet it isn't digits.

Comment: Also, test the value of `e.RowIndex`. It could be **(-1)**.

Comment: Also, also: **GridView3.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Value** could be **NULL** or **String.Empty**.

Comment: I've check all watch windows and there is nothing there

Comment: By checking your watch window, we mean while debugging your code with breakpoints, enter in that code to the watch window to get it's value.  Your issue is that the Convert.ToInt32() is trying to convert something that can't be an integer.

Comment: Put a break point in and look to see where it fails and look at your variables to see if they are the right types.  It is probably failing on one of the variables.  Look at your table make sure that the data types are the same as the variable data types.  If they are different then your database table then you will get this type of error.

Comment: I figured it out. I added a new column that handles int, but there is none in the sql database. Sorry. However, When I run it I'm getting another error on line `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Assigned", Assigned.Text):` saying _Object reference not set to an instance of an object_ any ideas?

Comment: Is Assigned.Text null, or allowed to be null?  If it is, you will want:
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Assigned", Assigned.Text ?? DBNull.Value);

?? operator means to take the second value if the first is null.

Comment: I was able to figure it out. Just had to change the ID in the HTML. Sorry. Dumb mistakes